# A beautiful way of displaying the interior in mathjax

Tags: general-topology

I currently do `$\circ{M}$` in order to display the interior (regarding topology). However it looks like this $\circ{M}$ and I would like it to be like that:

[image]

Is it possible to achieve the above in MathJax?

Comment: There is a LaTeX command: type 

> \overset{\circ}M

which will produce $\overset{\circ}M.$ Better still, the interior can be denoted as $\mathrm{Int}(M),$ which is a no-nonsense-straight-to-the-point notation.

Comment: This is better suited for TeX stackexchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\stackrel{\circ}{M}`

Shows as inline like $\stackrel{\circ}{M}$ and when in display mode it looks like:

$$\stackrel{\circ}{M}$$

Answer (score 2):

Here are two options:

\mathring{M}: $\mathring{M}$

\overset{\circ}{M}: $\overset{\circ}{M}$

Answer (score 2):

You can use the \mathring{} command to achieve the result you want, it should be generally better aligned than just putting a \circ over the letter, consider for example 
\mathring{J}=$\mathring{J}$  
\overset{\circ}{J}=$\overset{\circ}{J}$ 
\stackrel{\circ}{J}=$\stackrel{\circ}{J}$